# Why the connection name cannot be find in Bot application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-bot-service

Setup azure with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-bots-with-sso guide.
And used

```
private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, string connectionName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tokenProvider = turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider;
    var tokenResponse = await tokenProvider.GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext, connectionName, null, cancellationToken);

    if (tokenResponse == null)
    {
        var signInResource = await tokenProvider.GetSignInResourceAsync(turnContext, connectionName, cancellationToken);
        var card = new SigninCard
        {
            Text = "Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.Signin, "Авторизоваться", signInResource.SignInLink) },
        };

        var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = CardContentTypes.SigninCard,
            Content = card,
        });

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
        return null;
    }

    return tokenResponse.Token;
}
```

code to get token. But tokenProvider is returning null always. The search issue is showing that it is related with wrong connectionName, but I copied it from the Azure.
How can I solve this issue?

I tried several settings but with no result. Could some one give more information about Teams Bot Framework with Azure, how to get user token?